# Why does dir attribute not work inline text of same directional-type but works on inline-block text?

Tags: html, right-to-left, bidi

I read the links in another answer, but I still have some doubts. The `dir` attribute sets the **Base direction** of the text. So, if I set the base direction of `One اثنان three` to `ltr`, then it must remain as it is and if I set the `dir` to `rtl` then the output should be `three اثنان One`. The below script shows that it works as expected:

```html
<div dir="ltr">
  one اثنان three
</div>

<div dir="rtl">
  one اثنان three
</div>
```

So far so good. The `dir` attribute proves to set the base direction of text, but surprisingly it *does not* set the base direction if the enclosed letters belong to the same strongly typed category, rtl or ltr. E.g. If I set `dir` rtl to `one two three` then I expect `dir` to forcefully change the base direction and output the result as `three two one`. The following example shows that it doesn't:

```html
<div dir="ltr">  
  One two three  
</div>  

<div dir="rtl">  
  One two three  
</div>
```

Are the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) and [w3c article](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics), which claim that `dir` attribute sets the *base direction* of the text, technically incorrect?

Let us consider another scenario. The words `one`, `two` and `three` are declared to be inline-block overriding their default inline display type:

```html
    <div dir="rtl">
        <span style="display: inline-block">One</span>
        <span style="display: inline-block">Two</span>
        <span style="display: inline-block">Three</span>
    </div>
```

Interesting that `dir` change the base direction of inline-block text but not of the inline text. Here all three letters are ltr strongly typed just like the penultimate example but contrary to that example now the `dir` attribute is able to change the base direction of the text.

Comment: Isn't this the same [as your other question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157139/dir-rtl-vs-text-align-right-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: @j08691 The other question asks about how it is different from `text-align: left`. In this question I am asking whether the MDN definition is technically correct or not.

Comment: MDN is a wiki-editable resource and should not be relied upon as a source of truth (although it is almost always correct); whether its contents are correct or not is not really a programming question but rather a pedagogical question.

Comment: @TylerH I disagree. MDN  is stating a fact in a programming language and stackoverflow is the place where we ask whether certain facts are true or false.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the "is this website's facts correct" site, it is the specific programming question site. The question of whether `dir` sets the base direction of text is on-topic here; the question of whether MDN's definition of `dir` is correct is not.

Comment: @TylerH I still disagree. One you need to give a reference to the stackoverflow policy for that. Two MDN is not just a website; it's an official source/documentation for web technologies. In my opinion asking _"is xyz documentation technically correct?"_ is allowed as per stackoverflow's legal policies.

Answer (score 3):

The MDN definition is correct. What you are seeing is the effect of the Unicode bidirectional algorithm. The dir attribute sets the base direction (ie. directional context) for arranging clumps of same-direction sequences of characters. Read the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157139/dir-rtl-vs-text-align-right-what-is-the-difference-between-them) to understand the detail better.

Comment: Hi user @r12a, thanks for your explanation. I have edited the question to add some more points. Could you take a look at that?